# Why am I getting this action type cannot be undefined error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-redux

I'm trying to test out a login and logout link on my page, but whenever I try to do `window.dispatch(signup(user))`, I get this error message:

```
redux-logger.js:1 Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
```

I've double checked my actions and it looks fine to me:

```
export const RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER = 'RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER';
export const LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER = 'LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER';
export const RECEIVE_SESSION_ERRORS = 'RECEIVE_SESSION_ERRORS';

export const receiveCurrentUser = user => ({
  type: RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER,
  user
});

export const logoutCurrentUser = () => ({
  type: LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER,
});

export const receiveSessionErrors = errors => ({
  type: RECEIVE_SESSION_ERRORS,
  errors
});

export const login = user => dispatch => (
  APIUtil.login(user).then(user => dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(user)))
);

export const logout = () => dispatch => (
  APIUtil.logout().then(() => dispatch(logoutCurrentUser())),
  err => dispatch(receiveSessionErrors(err.responseJSON))
);

export const signup = user => dispatch => (
  APIUtil.signup(user).then(user => dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(user))), 
  err => dispatch(receiveSessionErrors(err.responseJSON))
);
```

I've also checked my reducers for the signup and I believe I'm importing the actions correctly:

```
import {RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER, LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER} from '../actions/session_action';

const _nullUser = Object.freeze({
  id: null
});

const sessionReducer = (state = _nullUser, action) => {
  Object.freeze(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER:
      return {id: action.currentUser.id};
    case LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER:
      return _nullUser;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default sessionReducer;
```

Any idea as to why this error is popping up or where it could be coming from?

**UPDATE**: It seems that the user signup goes through and the user is indeed in my database, despite the error message. But when I do `getState()` on the console, the user that I created doesn't appear in the state.

Here's a more detailed picture of the error message:

[image]

Comment: type is not a word reserved?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean???

Comment: It seems not in Javascript, nor in Ruby @thiaguerd.